# detect element where the function was called from

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know where my jQ function was called from...

In head:

```
function call_pl2(){
    $(this).text('some text');
}
```

in Body:

```
<p> <script> call_pl2();  </script> </p>
<!--              OR                 -->
<div> <script> call_pl2();  </script> </div>
```

Comment: I need to get this P or DIV or whatever element the function was called from...

Comment: Not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: I need to put some text inside div or other element where the function was called. In other words - replace this <script> call_pl2();  </script>  with text. I just didn't add the code to make it to not overload my question.

Comment: When you want to replace? on click? or anything else?

Comment: Still not clear what you want to acheive and when you want to change the text of the element.

Answer (score 1):

I got your point, I'm afraid you cannot get from the function the element that your js function is there, but each time that your function is called you can use another function and search your html content to see where this function is inside. I assume that this function is called ones from the html code when this is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to determine which element contains the the `script` tag (and, by extension, a particular call to `call_pl2()`) you could explicitly pass the containing element to `call_pl2()` as a parameter:

```js
$(function() {

  var call_p12 = function(element) {
    if ($(element).is('p')) {
      $(element).text('here is some text added to a paragraph');
    }
    if ($(element).is('div')) {
      $(element).text('here is some text added to a div');
    }
  }

  $('div, p').each(function() {
    call_p12($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

It would be relatively easy to modify the `call_p12()` function to swap in a more specific selector in the [jQuery is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/). For example `is('.someclass')` to check for a class value instead of a tag name.